# How to check response code on Android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

**CODE:**

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = postApiService.uploadFile(body, coordinatePoint, textToPost);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.check_internet), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

On this code, i think error is on `response.code()`

Because error code is like
`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc9`

on that `Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

So, how to get response code on android retrofit2?

Please would you let me know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc9` message because you are calling `makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)` in `onResponse`. Here, the second parameter expects a string resource ID of type `int`, but you are passing a response code instead. Simply convert your response code to a `String` to print out the correct value:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Toast.makeText` method, which you are using, is overloaded and using a string resource int as second argument.

Consider passing your second argument wrapped by `String.valueOf(response.code())`.